# Negative subjunctive

Tags: grammar, negation, subjunctive-mood

Some verbs require subjunctive, as in:

*The UN has demanded that all troops be withdrawn.*

A student has written:

*...my sense of responsibility demands that I can't do that.*

What is the negative subjunctive?:

*...my sense of responsibility demands that I not do that.*?

Comment: The "subjunctive" is really an infinitive form (without _to_; this is a _that_-clause, not an infinitive clause). The negative of an infinitive  without _to_ is formed by putting _not_ in front of the infinitive verb. So _that I not do it_ is the negation of _that I do it_. Very simple, but infinitives aren't inflected, after all; that's what _infinitive_ **means**.

Answer (score 2):

These three examples use the subjunctive:

1. 'I suggest that you not take the job.'
2. 'They recommended that your friend not leave the house.'
3. 'He asked that she not leave him.'

The next two don't.

- 'She begged him not to leave her.'
- 'He asked her not to leave him.'

The first three use the subjunctive form, the last two do not. Some verbs can do both, and others cannot.

Comment: I can see only five sentences.  Don't you mean 3 and 2 ?

Comment: I think he means 4 & 5.

Comment: @AlexLee - I proposed a change to your question, mostly as regards the formatting.  Please check if it's okay.